# Upgrading existing django_comments to Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-comments

I have a Django 1.4 site that uses the [Django comments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/) app. I'm upgrading my dev version to Django 1.5 and [extending the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) - I have a `Person` model which extends `AbstractBaseUser`, and `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'membership.Person'` in my settings.

At the moment the `django_comments` postgresql database table has a column `user_id` which references `auth_user(id)`:

```
"django_comments_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

There's nothing in that column because, so far, there are no user accounts in the system, other than my own admin user. I think I need to update the table to refer to my new `Person` model (which is stored in the `membership_person` table). In the future users will be able to create accounts and post logged-in comments.

What `ALTER TABLE` command should I use to change `django_comments` to refer to my new `Person` model? I'll have to do similar to the `django_comment_flags` table. Is there anything else I should watch out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this for the comments table:

```
ALTER TABLE django_comments DROP CONSTRAINT django_comments_user_id_fkey;
ALTER TABLE django_comments ADD CONSTRAINT django_comments_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES membership_person(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

And similar for the comment flags table:

```
ALTER TABLE django_comment_flags DROP CONSTRAINT django_comment_flags_user_id_fkey;
ALTER TABLE django_comment_flags ADD CONSTRAINT django_comment_flags_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES membership_person(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Hopefully that does the job and doesn't cause any problems. *crosses fingers*